# Parsing soapfault error code and error message android

Tags: android, ksoap2

I am calling a web service in android project using ksoap2.

I am receiving WS exception like below . Which is expected result for the input I am passing.

SoapFault - faultcode: 'soapenv:Server' faultstring: 'test.exceptions.WsException' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@5ebf64f

There is errorCode and errorMessage in detail field. But I am having problem while parsing it. Can anyone help how can I parse it.

Thanks

Comment: can you add some code to show what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like below by handling in exception.

```
     catch (SoapFault sf)
        {

            String errorCode="",errorMessage="";
            Element el=sf.detail.getElement(0);


            for(int i=0;i<=el.getChildCount();i++)
            {

                el=el.getElement(0);
                if(el.getName().equals("WsException"))
                {
                    Element elementec=el.getElement(0);
                    errorCode=elementec.getChild(0).toString();

                    Element elementem=el.getElement(1);
                    errorMessage=elementem.getChild(0).toString();


                }

            }

            result="error Code "+ errorCode + "error Message " + errorMessage ;

        }
```